# maps - deleting data

Tags: dictionary, go

How does one delete data from a map in Go? For example, having

```
m := map[string]string{ "key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" };
```

I want to make m drop the "key1" without copying the entire map by iterating over its keys (which could get big in some uses). Is it enough to assign a nil value to "key1", or will that still keep the key in the map structure with an assigned value of nil? That is, if I later iterate over the keys of the map, will "key1" appear?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> [Deletion of map elements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Deletion_of_map_elements)
>
> The built-in function `delete` removes the element with key k from a map
>   m.
>
> ```
> delete(m, k)  // remove element m[k] from map m
> ```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
    fmt.Println(m)
    delete(m, "key1")
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Output:

```
map[key1:val1 key2:val2]
map[key2:val2]
```